# Animation changed when I push down to NLA track from Action Editor

Tags: animation

**I created a jump action in Action editor but when I push down to NLA track then it suddenly change the root bone change its rotation and hand stop moving**

[image]

**This is ss where I created Jump action**

[image]

**This is ss where I moved it to NLA editor and it change it's rotation and hand reset to it's original position**

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to guess, maybe share your file (only the armature and its action)?

Comment: @moonboots Thank u , will share file soon :)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4mNkzr1M" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4mNkzr1M/)
@moonboots here it is

Comment: also attached in main question

Answer (score 0):

Your root bone is rotated 0° in the *jump* action:

[image]

But it is rotated 90° in the *walk* action:

[image]

So it's normal that it rotates 90° when you switch from one to the other. The weird thing is that it should come back to 0° when it plays the jump action, even though the *walk* strip is set to *Extrapolation > Hold*. Maybe someone will understand, that said, to fix your problem, maybe simply change the *Rotation* of the *jump* action to 90° as well?

Comment: I try with changing root rotation it solve problem but it also changes loc. and rot of other bones too while moving to NLA . Look like there is mistake in animation may be , so I try with complete new file and reanimate jumping animation but this time it remain as it is while I move to NLA.
Can't figure out whats the problem with first jumping animation , it also changes hand IK to FK